# Access server using Browser and IP instead of DNS

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, ubuntu, dns, apache2

I want to access my test site from my home by using Firefox and entering IP instead of DNS.

My server is AWS Ubuntu and It has Mysql, Apache2 installed.

I want to access my test site like this in Firefox: x.x.x.x/test

But it showed me 404.

When I type in Firefox like this it works fine: x.x.x.x

I have no idea how to make this work.

Here's what I did in my server.

```
cd /var/www
sudo mkdir test
sudo cp wordpress test/
cd test
sudo mv -R test public
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data public
sudo chmod -R 775 public
cd /etc/apache2/sites-available
sudo cp 000-default.conf test.conf
sudo vim test.conf
```

Here is test.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName test
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/test/public
    <Directory /var/www/test/public/>
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Here goes command again

```
sudo a2ensite test.conf
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Now I goto my Firefox and enter my AWS elastic IP in address bar like this:

```
x.x.x.x/test
```

Which gives me 404

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing a mistake in the document root. Change your Apache Configuration to below and restart apache then `x.x.x.x/test` it will work or type this url `x.x.x.x/test/public` in your browser.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName x.x.x.x
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/test
    <Directory /var/www/test>
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: what files do you have in test directory do you have any file by name index.html or index.php? Also change ServerName to your IP address and restart apache

Comment: It's a whole copy of downloaded wordpress files from wordpress.org. It has index.php

Comment: Check my above comment